# Sort a python dictionary by values and slice top 5 rows into another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

My Original dictionary has many keys and values as below

`orig_dict = {'humor':8, 'fiction':8, 'novel':8, ...}` as below table

[image]

I want to sort the dictionary by values and add the top 5 rows into another dictionary. How do I achieve that?  Thanks.

Expected output:

`top5_dict = {'humor':8, 'fiction':8, 'novel':8, 'telugu':8, 'Russian':8}`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a reverse sorted dictionary and slice first 5 values.

```
orig_dict = {'humor': 8, 'fiction': 8, 'novel': 8, 'paper': 1, 'tkinter': 2, 'linux': 8}

sorted_dict = {key: value for key, value in sorted(orig_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)[:5:]}
print(sorted_dict)

# {'humor': 8, 'fiction': 8, 'novel': 8, 'linux': 8, 'tkinter': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
orig_dict = {'humor': 8, 'fiction': 8, 'novel': 8, 'telugu': 8, 'Russian': 8, 'French': 8, 'linux': 8, 'money': 8,
             'paper': 1
    , 'onlineclas': 1, 'essaypay': 1, 'physics': 2, 'economic': 1, 'math': 1, 'essaywriting': 1, 'essayh': 1,
             'tkinter': 2, 'codenewt': 1, 'codes': 1}
top5_dict = dict(sorted(orig_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)[:5])
print(top5_dict)

# {'humor': 8, 'fiction': 8, 'novel': 8, 'telugu': 8, 'Russian': 8}
```